# Permission change

Tags: 18.04, lts

I am having trouble with permissions on a second HDD. It is a storage/Data drive that I have been using but for some reason the permission has changed from "me" to "root" within a minute or two. How do I stop this from happening and what may be the cause of it happening in the first place? I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: It is formatted as  msdos and is a second drive in a cradle where the dvd drive was. There is only Ubuntu and not a dual boot to windoze. The owner did change from me to root. I created a folder and saved a file into it and when I went to rename the folder the permissions and ownership had changed. Why I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a thread in UbuntuForums [HERE](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211159).

Probably it's because the filesystem format of your HDD is ext4.
run `sudo blkid` to see the UUID of your HDD and check if the filesystem is ext4.
Below command will make you the owner of HDD:

`sudo chown [YOUR_USER_NAME]:[YOUR_USER_NAME] /media/user/[UUID_WITHOUT_QUOTE_SIGNS]`

Comment: There is something very strange going on here. It is formatted as msdos (FAT) but I have found that there is a "Data" in /mnt/Data that has all the files in it and is owned by root also a "Data" in   /media/dennis/Data which is owned by me and is empty. The last day or so the Data drive was coming up as Data1 but was still editable by me. Now from one minute to the next I created a folder and saved a file from Libre Writer and when I went back to change the folder name permissions had changed and I could not edit it. There is only Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on the laptop.

Comment: @Dennis Can you access the contents of your HDD with root privileges? try `sudo nautilus`

Comment: I can access the drive from files and when I do sudo /media/dennis/Data1 it brings up the files but I still can not edit or add folders to the drive. This is the terminal info when I do the nautilus thing.  There is more to this but makes the message too long.

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1          63 1465149167 1465149105 698.7G  c W95 

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Comment: Is it possible to attach a screenshot?